# vscode -- How to run `docker` in a task ? -- Docker-Build-Task does not work

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

### Situation and Problem

I am running **macOS Mojave 10.14.5**, **upgraded bash** like described [here](https://itnext.io/upgrading-bash-on-macos-7138bd1066ba) and have a **TeXlive docker container** (basically [that one](https://hub.docker.com/r/thomasweise/docker-texlive-full/)), that I want to call to typeset LaTeX files. This does work very well and also execution with this following `tasks.json` worked flawlessly up unti some recent update (that I cannot pin down, as I am not using this daily).

`tasks.json`

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "runit",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "command": "docker",
            "args": [
                "run",
                "-v",
                "${fileDirname}:/doc/",
                "-t",
                "-i",
                "mytexlive",
                "pdflatex",
                "${fileBasename}"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "test",
            "command": "echo",
            "args": [
                "run",
                "-v",
                "${fileDirname}:/doc/",
                "-t",
                "-i",
                "mytexlive",
                "pdflatex",
                "${fileBasename}"
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

Trying to run docker yields a "command not found" :

```sh
> Executing task: docker run -v /path/to/file:/doc/ -t -i mytexlive pdflatex file_name.tex <

/usr/local/bin/bash: docker: command not found
The terminal process command '/usr/local/bin/bash -c 'docker run -v /path/to/file:/doc/ -t -i mytexlive pdflatex file_name.tex'' failed to launch (exit code: 127)
```

... while trying to echo, works just fine.

```sh
> Executing task: echo run -v /path/to/file:/doc/ -t -i mytexlive pdflatex file_name.tex <

run -v /path/to/file:/doc/ -t -i mytexlive pdflatex file_name.tex
```

Even though, it once worked just like described above *and* the very same command works in the terminal, it fails now if I execute it as a build-task. Hence, my

### Question

> How to use `docker` in a build-task ?

or fix the problem in the above set up.

#### additional notes

Trying the following yielded the same "command not found"

```
{
    "type": "shell", "label": "test",
    "command": "which", "args": ["docker"]
}
```

... even though this works:

```sh
bash$ /usr/local/bin/bash -c 'which docker'
/usr/local/bin/docker
bash$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

#### edit: One more note:

I am using a context entry to start vscode with an automator script that runs the following bash command with the element 'right-clicked' passed as the variable:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/code -n "$1"
```

Comment: It does work again. With the very same settings though; nothing has changed. What do I do with this question now? It seems to be a reasonable post but the cause for the problem was a bug (that I can not reproduce) most likely?

Comment: Same thing happened again! Seemingly, nothing changed. Just doesn't do it anymore, if I run the build task (but the command works if pasted into the terminal). I tried to just close everything and restart, and voilá -- works. Only, thing I did, was to install a extension/plugin.

Comment: Once again. Found [this issue on github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/6579) saying it had been fixed. Seems like I have to start a new thread there.

Comment: kind of a similar issue, but not exactly. i want to be able to add a tag to images. read this article: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/reference, but when i create a task of type 'docker-build', vscode complains it is not a valid task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So since there hasn't been any progress here and I got help on GitHub: I will just answer myself such that others led here searching for a solution won't be let down.

Please give all the acknowledgement to **joaomoreno for [his answer here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92262#issuecomment-607076087)**

---

Turns out that by starting vscode via a context-entry there is some issue with an enviroment variable. Starting like this fixed that problem thus far:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
VSCODE_FORCE_USER_ENV=1 /usr/local/bin/code -n "$1"
```